# keras.preprocessing.image.load_img "UnidentifiedImageError"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, loadimage

I'm trying to follow [this](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/) Keras tutorial for image segmentation. It seems to run fine in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/oxford_pets_image_segmentation.ipynb#scrollTo=9lYtYMkEaxmd), but running locally, I get the following error:

```
for j, path in enumerate(batch_target_img_paths):
    img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size, color_mode="grayscale")

...

Exception has occurred: UnidentifiedImageError
cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000020130390400>
  File "C:\Computer Vision\main_tutorial.py", line 203, in __getitem__
    img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size, color_mode="grayscale")
  File "C:\Computer Vision\main_tutorial.py", line 102, in main
    model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Computer Vision\main_tutorial.py", line 211, in <module>
    main()
```

I've verified the path is correct:

`C:\Computer Vision\oxford-iiit-pet\train\annotations\._Abyssinian_10.png`

The file in question `._Abyssinian_10.png` doesn't appear to be a valid image (I believe it's a target mask) and can't be opened in a regular image viewing application.

Is there an environment or platform issue I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this error then the image is probably corrupted or of `NoneType`.

You cannot salvage this image in my experience and you are better off just removing it with the code below which checks if the image is valid as a `PNG` and if it isn't then remove the image. If you have `JPEG` images then you can just use `jpeg` instead.

You would have to run this over the entire directory of your images.

```
import cv2
import imghdr
import os

image_path = "C:\Computer Vision\oxford-iiit-pet\train\annotations\._Abyssinian_10.png"
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
img_type = imghdr.what(image_path)
if img_type != "png":
    os.remove(image_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I just realised the error was my fault - the target folder contains the correct image mask file: `annotations\Abyssinian_10.png` which I should be using, not `annotations\._Abyssinian_10.png`

Comment: @TomSelleck ah I see no problem then if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The error was a mistake on my part.

The `annotations/trimaps` folder contains two files for each original image:

`._Abyssinian_1.png`

`Abyssinian_1.png`

I was trying to load the incorrect file `._Abyssinian_1.png` where I should have been loading `Abyssinian_1.png`